# Matlab: mean value in 4-d matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, mean, netcdf

I have a 4-d matrix (time, one_variable, Y_location, X_location) in Matlab.

Here is the 4-d matrix looks like:

```
>> size (npp_data_pft1)
ans =
100     1   289   570
```

100 means 100 timesteps; 1 means only 1 variable here; 289 and 570 are the y and x gridded cell indices.

How to get a mean value in a specific region?

For example, I like to get a mean value in timestep 1 within a region at 33 < Y_location < 47 and 112 < X_location < 176.

Comment: Please clarify what the problem is (preferably with a reproducible example), the existing answers already seem to do what you ask.

Comment: if it makes it easier for you, you could use `permute` to get rid of that singleton dimension

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the trick:

```
M = npp_data_pft1(:, 1, 33:47, 112:176);
mean(reshape(M,[],size(M,3)*size(M,4))');
```

In this example the answer will output values each with the mean of the region you selected per frame.   I reshaped the 4D matrix to a 2D one. That matrix has 100 lines (total # of frames) and 975 columns (total # of pixels in the selected region). Then just using `mean` on that 2D matrix will yield the mean value of the entire region per frame. (I used `'` to get the mean working in the right dimension, instead you can use `mean(...,2)`)

Comment: Can you try this method: x=randi(10,[100 1 10 25]); mean_x = nanmean(nanmean(x,3),4); and compare the results with your method. These two methods generate different results.

Comment: you are correct I wasn't careful enough with the reshape, now the dimensions are correct. (see `[],size(...)` instead of `size(..),[]`). The output of both will have the right dimensions but one will reshape values from the same row of different frames rather the array of a single frame...

Comment: note that the will be still a floating point accuracy difference between my answer and @Luis Mendo. Apparently there is a vanishing difference in the answer if you mean a vector vs take twice the mean of an array of the same # of elements. For example try `a=rand(1000);b=mean(a(:))-mean(mean(a))`

Answer (score 10):

One way to do it is to extract your region and then take the mean.

```
A = npp_data_pft1(1, 1, 33:47, 112:176);
mean(A(:))    % returns scalar value
```

Comment: From the question: "I like to get a mean value in timestep 1"

Comment: Ah indeed, you actually extract time and region.

Comment: Sorry. how about just getting the regional average, but we still keep the timestep from 1 to 100.

Comment: I like to get the spatial average in a specific region for each timestep. For example, size(mean_ npp_data_pft1) = 100 1 1 1

Comment: We got two methods, but I got complete results: x=randi(10,[100 1 10 25]); method#1: mean_x = nanmean(nanmean(x,3),4); method#2: M = x(1:100, 1, 1:10, 1:25); mean_x = nanmean(reshape(M,size(M,3)*size(M,4),[]))';

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to do the average for more than one time value. In that case I suggest the following, where `1:20` represents the range of time values you want to observe:

```
mean(mean(npp_data_pft1(1:20, 1, 33:47, 112:176),3),4);
```

This gives a 20x1 vector with the desired averages.

Note that the second argument of [`mean`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) indicates along which dimension the average is computed.